# Having trouble with a simple problem. Evaluate this Surface integral.

Tags: integration, vectors

I feel like this problem is very simple, but no matter what I try, I just can't seem to get the correct answer: $\sqrt6$

Define the Parametrized surface $X:D->R^3$ $$X(s,t)=(2s,s+t,2t)$$
where D is the triangular region with verticies at (0,0), (0,1) and (1,1) 
$$\int\int_{x}ydS$$

The first thing I did was draw the triangle defined by the 3 points. I am unsure if that triangle is on the parameter "graph" (s,t) or the (x,y,z) coordinate graph. The line that defines the triangle is y=x; or s=t.

I'm not sure what I was supposed to do next. I took the normal vector to the triangle. 2 vectors on the triangle$<1,0,0>$ and $<0,1,0>$ cross product: $<0,0,1>$ the magnitude is $\sqrt1=1$

Normally when I do surface integrals, I'm allowed to define x,y and z myself. But in this problem, I'm already given a set of parameters and I have no idea when and where to implement them. So I decided to just take the integral without parametrizing and see what happens. 
$$\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\int_{y=0}^{y=x}y*dS=\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{1^3}{(2*3)}=1/6$$  Which is not the right answer. 
How can I implement the parameters they gave me to solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is not the same surface as $D$.  $S$ is defined in terms of $X$ which is in turn defined in terms of $s$ and $t$.  You need to find out how much $x,y$ and $z$ move as $s$ and $t$ move.

$dS = ||\frac{\partial X}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial X}{\partial t}||$

$(2,1,0)\times(0,1,2) = ||(2,-2,4)|| = \sqrt{24}$

$dS = \sqrt{24} ds\, dt$

So, if $s$ and $t$ had the freedom to define a 1x1 square, $S$ would be a $\sqrt{24}$ sq unit parallelogram.

$y = (s+t)$

$\int_0^1\int_0^t (s+t) \sqrt{24} \,ds\, dt$

$\int_0^1 ((1/2)s^2+st) \sqrt{24} \, dt |_0^t$

$\int_0^1 ((3/2)t^2) \sqrt{24} \, dt$

$((1/2)t^3) \sqrt{24}|_0^1 $

$(1/2) \sqrt{24}$

$\sqrt{6}$

Comment: Thanks for answering! one quick question, when you began to integrate, did you choose the bounds based on the original triangle? meaning the triangle was on the 'parameterized' coordinate graph?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate it :) :)